Способы создания копии элемента в C#
Стоит задача получить копию класса как объект, чтобы при создании двух объектов типа Character, они были как две самостоятельные сущности и не ссылались на одну область памяти.
Допустим, при создании двух Warrior, они были как два самостоятельных объекта со своими полями и методами.
Character Warrior_1
Character Warrior_2
Какие существуют способы реализации такой задачи; или, может, есть какой-то общий способ.

Реализуйте интерфейс ICloneable и пропишите в нем создание копии из текущего объекта любым удобным для вас способом (пример).  Способы могут быть разные, хоть сериализация/десериализация, тут все как-бы зависит от конечных целей и желаний.

with не подойдёт?

@AlexanderPetrov Для record'ов покатит. А для произвольного объекта непонятно, как его правильно склонировать, так что пускай реализует себе IClonable.

Причём здесь наследование? "при создании двух Warrior они были как два самостоятельных объекта со своими полями и методами" - они будут двумя самостоятельными объектами, если вы будете создавать каждый их них с помощью new. Наследование классов никак не связывает между собой объекты этих классов.
P. S. А, тогда такие варианты:
partial class Warrior : ICloneable {
    // 1 интерфейс `ICloneable`
    public object Clone() {
        return new Warrior() {
            ValueTypeProperty1 = this.ValueTypeProperty1,
            ReferenceTypeProperty1 = this.ReferenceTypeProperty1.Clone()
        }
    }
    // 2 конструктор копирования
    public Warrior(Warrior warrior) {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(warrior);
        ValueTypeProperty1 = warrior.ValueTypeProperty1;
        ReferenceTypeProperty1 = warrior.ReferenceTypeProperty1.Clone();
    }
    // 3 статический метод копирования
    public static Warrior From(Warrior warrior) {
        return warrior is null ? null : (Warrior)warrior.Clone();
    }
    // 4 конструктор с наилучшими параметрами по умолчанию
    public Warrior() {
        ValueTypeProperty1 = theMostCommonValue;
        ReferenceTypeProperty1 = new ReferenceType1(theBestCommonValue);
    }
}
Warrior_2 = (Warrior)Warrior_1.Clone(); // 1
Warrior_2 = new Warrior(Warrior_1); // 2
Warrior_2 = Warrior.From(Warrior_1); // 3
Warrior_2 = new Warrior(); // 4

У каждого из вариантов есть свои особенности применения.

Прошу прощения, если как то запутал, я исправил вопрос по вашему замечанию, надеюсь стало понятнее.
Да, создание нового объекта через new это вариант, но при этом мне прийдется вручную указывать аргументы, а мне нужно автоматизировать это создание.

@LUCY Ну сделайте фабрику, которая печёт ваших рыцарей как пирожки. Или в самом рыцаре сделайте конструктор параметрами по умолчанию. Да полно вариантов.
